# How general is this property about correlation and the sum of two normal RVs?

Tags: probability, statistics, convolution, correlation

Edited to make this more concrete:

Given a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ that is jointly normal with means / sd's  $\mu_1,\mu_2, \sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and correlation $\rho$, the sum of $S=X_1+X_2$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_1+ \mu_2$ and variance $\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2 + 2\rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y$.

In particular, as $\rho$ increases, the CDF of the sum 'rotates' about $(\mu_1+ \mu_2,1/2).$

Now for other rvs, not normal, intuitively it seems like something like this property should generically be true: when you add two random variables and only their correlation increases (perhaps a more formal correlation order is needed than simply the number $\rho$), the CDF of the sum should rotate about the mean $\mu_X+\mu_Y$.

My intuition is that as the rv's get more correlated the chance that their sum takes on very high or very low values should monotonically decrease. This is clear for the normal case, but can it be formalized for some larger class in general? Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I think I can see what you are saying. You can calculate the equation of the major and minor axes exactly, and from that you can show how the angle (relative to the horizontal axis) increases as $\rho$ increases. If the question stays open, maybe I'll find time to write an answer. If you google around though, you can find the formulas. I can at least share an R code that plots all this...

Comment: Thanks any answer or guidance would be very helpful. I can't seem to find the formulas you refer to. I was googling things like "major axis of convolution" or "major axis of sum of random variables"

Comment: Ah... nevermind... I read it as the sum but was thinking about the regression line. Sorry!